# How is the "surface measure" on a manifold defined?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

Let

- $k,n\in\mathbb N$ with $k\le n$
- $M$ be a $k$-dimensional $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$
- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^k$ be open, $\phi:\Omega\to M$ be a global chart of $M$ and $$g_\phi(x):=\det\left(\left({\rm D}\phi(x)\right)^\ast {\rm D}\phi(x)\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in U$$

Now, let $\lambda^k$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^k)$,  $\sqrt{g_\phi}{\rm d}\left.\lambda^k\right|_U$ denote the measure with density $\sqrt{g_\phi}$ with respect to $\left.\lambda^k\right|_U$ and $$S_M:=\phi_\ast\left(\sqrt{g_\phi}{\rm d}\left.\lambda^k\right|_U\right)$$ the pushforward measure of $\sqrt{g_\phi}{\rm d}\left.\lambda^k\right|_U$ with respect to $\phi$. $S_M$ is a measure on $\mathcal B(M)$ and we're able to verify that $S_M(A)$ is the surface area of $A\in\mathcal B(M)$.

> I'm searching for a generalization of the concept described above for more general $M$. In particular, the $M$ I've got in mind is the finite union of triangles in $\mathbb R^3$. Two different triangles can be assumed to intersect only along one common side or at one common vertex and two different sides can intersect only at one common vertex.
>
> I've searched the internet for a couple of hours, but couldn't find anything (Actually, I wasn't even able to find the construction of $S_M$ above anywhere). So, is there any good textbook on that topic?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your $S_M$ depends not only on $M$, but also on $\phi$; to define an area form intrinsic to $M$ you need to equip $M$ with a metric, impose additional assumptions (for instance that the metric is pulled back from the ambient space), or specify a particular $\phi$.

A typical construction for the second approach for triangle meshes is to observe that one can construct an affine chart $\phi$ on each triangle (with vertices $\mathbf{p}_i$) from a canonical unit triangle $\mathcal{T} = 0 \leq u,v, u+v \leq 1$ in the plane by the triangle's barycentric coordinates:
$$\phi(u,v) = \mathbf{p}_1 + u(\mathbf{p}_2-\mathbf{p}_1) + v(\mathbf{p}_2-\mathbf{p}_1).$$

It is easy to show that the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^3$ pulls back to a constant metric $d\phi\otimes d\phi$ on $\mathcal{T}$, so that your desired area measure is, analogously to your formula,
$$S_{\mathrm{im}\ \phi} = \phi_*\left(\|d\phi\|\,d\lambda_{\mathcal{T}}\right) = \phi_*\left(\sqrt{\det \left[\begin{array}{cc}\|(\mathbf{p}_2-\mathbf{p}_1)\|^2 & (\mathbf{p}_2-\mathbf{p}_1)\cdot (\mathbf{p}_3-\mathbf{p}_1)\\(\mathbf{p}_3-\mathbf{p}_1)\cdot (\mathbf{p}_2-\mathbf{p}_1) & \|(\mathbf{p}_3-\mathbf{p}_1)\|^2\end{array}\right]}\,d\lambda_{\mathcal{T}}\right).$$

Comment: I've considered $M\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ as being equipped with the metric induced by $\mathbb R^n$. And we can show that $S_M$ is independent of the choice of $\phi$.

Comment: Do you know a good textbook which constructs such measures? Please note that I know almost nothing about manifolds. The only think I know about are submanifolds and how we integrate over them. I need to deal with the triangle scenario described above only for a single application. So, I don't want to dive to deep into "manifolds with boundary", "manifolds with corners", etc.

Comment: @0xbadf00d hmm I don't know a textbook that looks specifically at the triangle case, but the finite element literature has surely examined such problems in depth. What specific application do you have in mind?

Comment: My application is [ray tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics)). The surface measure participates in the so-called "throughput measure", see, for example, [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=LG6rCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq=ray+space+throughput+measure&source=bl&ots=hkjVkAWX0T&sig=sAlHJqT2eHWV4cfbEfmtWitp9II&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfipG_8_bbAhVDIVAKHUgyCkIQ6AEIPDAG#v=onepage&q=ray%20space%20throughput%20measure&f=false).